# Problems running proxychains on Tails 1.6 does not find firefox

Tags: tails, socks

I boot Tails 1.6 with persistence and with admin password in order to install proxychains then I install via apt-get an edit the /etc/proxychains.conf to add socks5 after Tor, I save the changes and proceed to run  proxychains firefox from the command line and this is what I get:

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ proxychains firefox
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
/usr/bin/proxychains: 9: exec: firefox: not found
```

I also tried:

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ proxychains tor browser
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
Oct 21 19:53:44.329 [notice] Tor v0.2.6.10 (git-71459b2fe953a1c0) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.19-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1e and Zlib 1.2.7.
Oct 21 19:53:44.330 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at hxxps://ww.torproject,org/download/download#warning
Oct 21 19:53:44.330 [warn] Command-line option 'browser' with no value. Failing.
Oct 21 19:53:44.330 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Anyone can help me on this? I googled a few hours and Im not able to find the answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing the "-" between tor and browser it should look like,

> sudo proxychains tor-browser

or

> sudo proxychains /usr/local/bin/tor-browser